# Apache Wink Request Handler

Tags: java, compiler-errors, apache-wink

I am working to try and incorporate Amber into Wink for Oauth and running
into an error on the custom Handler.  I have created a HandlerFactory,
RequestHandler, and added the wink-properities.properties configuration as
well as modified the web.xml with the properties file location.

The error is related to my HandlerFactory class to load the RequestHandler:

```
    public List<? extends org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandler>
getRequestHandlers() {

    return Arrays.asList(se.influen.wink.handler.OauthRequestHandler);

    }
```

Here is the error:

```
wink/handler/OauthHandlersFactory.java:[15,44] cannot find symbol

[ERROR] symbol  : class handler
```

Is there something I am missing to get this custom handler to work? Or is
there a better way to incorporate Amber into a Wink application?  At the
current time I am doing nothing more than attempting to get the handler to
generate a response.

The goal is to add Oauth2 security into the Wink application.

Comment: I don't quite understand: is it a compilation error or runtime? If it's compilation, check the classpath. If runtime post the actual exception.

Comment: It is compilation error and the error message is above (I will edit with the full error).  I guess the core of the question is how to add to the generic class list                                          return Arrays.asList(se.influen.wink.handler.OauthRequestHandler);      where List <? extends RequestHandler>.  It doesn't recognize the class I am specifying yet the files are in the same package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `se.influen.wink.handler.OauthRequestHandler`?
According to the method signature you should return instance of class, so `new` may help:

```
public List<? extends org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandler> getRequestHandlers() {

return Arrays.asList(new se.influen.wink.handler.OauthRequestHandler());

}
```